# React Redux Set Item Complete

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, reducers

I have a feeling I'm so close to this... I have a to do list application I'm building.

A user can click on a button labeled "complete" to mark that specific item as complete.

My thinking on this is, when the user clicks that button to only update "completed" state to true.

For some reason the text within the state changed to "undefined" from the selected item and another item adds to the state when clicking "complete"

Here is my action:

```
export function completeTodo() {
    return {
        type: "COMPLETE_TODO",
        completed: true
    }
}
```

Here is my reducer:

```
case "COMPLETE_TODO": {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                todos: [{
                    text: action.text,
                    completed: action.completed,
                    id: getId(state)
                }, ...state.todos]
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates new array with one new todo object and all the previous todos (so basically you are adding one todo to the beginning of the array from previous state):

```
[
  {
    text: action.text,
    completed: action.completed,
    id: getId(state)
  },
  ...state
]
```

You should filter out old todo object:

```
[
  {
    text: action.text,
    completed: action.completed,
    id: getId(state)
  },
  ...state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== getId(state))
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The main issue I'm having is the text is updating to "undefined" and I'm unsure why.

Answer (score 0):

Your COMPLETE_TODO action doesn't have a *text* field so the reducer assigns undefined to the state.

As far as I understand, you dont want to change the items' text property when completed. You can remove the *text* assignment from the reducer.